# Sums of random variables, one being strictly positive

Tags: probability, summation

I have the following problem. Let $X$ be a random variable and $Y$ a strictly positive random variable. Is it true under no further general assumptions that:

$$\mathbb P( X + Y \leq x) < \mathbb P (X \leq x)  $$

If X and Y are independent i think this can be seen by conditioning on $Y=y$, bounding  $\mathbb P(X \leq x -y ) < \mathbb P(X \leq x )$ and then appltying the total law of probability. In general I suspect this relation does not hold, but it would be nice to find a counterexample. Many thanks :)

Comment: Consider the events the probabilities measure. Isnt one always a subset of the other?

Comment: They are. I thought about this but then got confused in thinking about joint laws. Somehow I wrongly thought that since the variables on the left hand and right sides have different distributions, they would have to be calculated according to different probabilities. This is embarassing. Thank you.